# cd /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log throwing "no such file or directory"

Tags: xubuntu, mongodb

No Such file or directory when I tried this command cd /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log after installing mongodb using sudo apt-get install -y mongodb. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 which I upgraded to xubuntu in my oracle virtual box.

any workaround? am i missing something like access rights or environment variable setup?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you specified a file `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`, while `cd` (Change Directory) wants a directory. Do

```
cd /var/log/mongodb
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

oh thank you. I didn't realize that. and after I go to the directory I use cat mongodb.log to view the logs.

[image]